# Filter Query with extension method in group by context

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Lets say I have the following query:

```
From row In DataSet.A
Where row.Position <> 5
Group row By row.Name Into eGroup = Group
Select New With {
    .Name = Name,
    .Amount = eGroup.Count(Function(x) x.Money)
}
```

The DataSet has a field (Date). Due to the grouping the field doesn't exist after the grouping anymore. So if I want to filter by date I have to do this before I group.

I have a List that looks like:

```
Dim j as New List(of Integer)
j.Add(1)
j.Add(2)
```

Now I want to filter by month. I know that I can use

```
.Where(Function(el) ls.Contains(datepart(month,el.date)))
```

But if I set this behind `Where row.Position <> 5` the query doesn't run anymore since it is like broken and cannot connect to the code afterwords.

Anyone can tell me how to set the filter?

Comment: How does C# involves?

Comment: As an aside, are you sure that it is correct to `Count` the money for each group instea of `Sum`?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it is ok as it is, the original query is a bit longer and could have been a bit confusing so I used a shorter version. Alex: It doesnt matter if the solution is in c# or vb. Many programmer can programm both (.NET). I could rewrite a c# solution. So I dont care if the solution is in c# or vb, that is why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do:

```
Dim months = {1, 2}
Dim query = From row In DataSet.A
            Where row.Position <> 5 AndAlso months.Contains(row.Date.Month)
            Group row By name Into eGroup = Group
            Select New With {
                Key .Name = name,
                .Amount = eGroup.Count(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("Money"))
            }
```

Comment: Didnt come up with it since I thought Contains is not available in query method. Know I know it better. Thanks for your help!